# What were some major breakthroughs in chemistry in 2016?

Tags: history-of-chemistry

What breakthroughs have been made in the different fields of chemistry in the past 366 days? This might help me and others know advances made in different field.

I know this question is too broad, but however there are many  interesting advances in all sorts of branches that have been made this year, which I might have missed.

Inspired by "What were some major mathematical breakthroughs in 2016?", on *Mathematics Stack Exchange*

Comment: While this would be an interesting topic of discussion, I feel that it is too broad. Hence a cast a vote to close. Sorry.

Comment: http://yearinreview.cenmag.org